# Angular binding with form automatically

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zpufky7u/1/

I have many forms on the site, which was working fine, but just suddenly angular is binding all the forms with `class="ng-pristine ng-valid"`

Is this a setting or what can cause angular to auto-bind forms?

I'm using angular version: angular#1.4.7

Following is my form, as you can see there is no model inside form

```
<form name="app_bundle_notification_type" method="post">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label class="required">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="app_bundle_notification_type_isNewsletter" name="app_bundle_notification_type[isNewsletter]" required="required" value="1" checked="checked">
                        Yes, I would like to receive email newsletter for new deals, coupons and news.
                    </label>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row m-y-1">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="app_bundle_notification_type__token" name="app_bundle_notification_type[_token]" class="form-control" value="b-_qAF6LHFy_GtPlsFG3iguhVXfGsj38TXm22Ke8j0k">
</form>
```

Angular app.js

```
define(['angular'], function() {

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.init = function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
    };

    return app;
});
```

So far I found the issue, if you do `angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);` then it is binding the form. it was not causing this issue before.

Comment: its automatically set by angular. See angular documentation for form : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: classes such as `ng-pristine` and `ng-valid` are added by Angular whenever you use `ngModel`.  You can ignore those classes if you don't need them.

Comment: I dont have any ngModel inside my form, all my forms were working fine, then all of suddenly they are not working anymore and I found this issue. angular is binding all my forms automatically, which prevents them from getting submitted. so each time any of the form is submitted, it will just add class ng-submitted or ng-submitting

Comment: I'd suggest you roll your code back to before it stopped working and see what you changed to cause it to stop working; I would be extremely surprised if it's caused by angular adding some classes to the form fields. (Note there's no "action" attribute on your form; do you have a submit handler somewhere that's supposed to take care of that? If so, that's the first place I'd look. If not, well, that's your answer.)

Comment: Ya no action is fine, because if I disable the js or remove angular, it starts working again.  It's defo the angular issue, which does not make sense, because it was working before. (no rollback option I have available for angular lib)

Comment: By "rollback" I meant roll back your own code (not angular itself) to the last working version, so you can see what changed to cause it to stop working. (I'm not sure how you're successfully POSTing a form with no action or submit handler, or why you're using angular but not ngModel, but I guess that's kind of beyond the scope of the question...)

Comment: @DanielBeck check demo here https://jsfiddle.net/zpufky7u/1/

Comment: `angular.bootstrap` is an alternate way to initiate angular when you haven't used an `ng-app` attribute.   If you weren't using that before, and didn't have an `ng-app` attribute anywhere, then you were never actually using angular. So it's no wonder you weren't seeing angular bindings...   (Or, if you do have an `ng-app` attribute in the doc, then you don't need to `.bootstrap()` it)

Comment: I dont have ng-app, because I need to auto bind. But how can I solve the jsfiddle demo? maybe you can edit it out and show me how to fix it without removing angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

> For this reason, **Angular prevents the default action** (form submission
>   to the server) **unless the `<form>` element has an action attribute**
>   specified.

New version accepts empty `action=""`, check release version at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3776

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using a form tag around your form, Angular automatically adds those classes to each `ng-model` inside your form.

This allows you much more control over the elements inside your form to perform any validation or logic you want your form to capture or enforce before submitting.

Much of it is listed in the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Ya but I don't have any ng-model inside my form, let me share my form :)

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `ng-model`? Have you tried replacing `value` on your input with `ng-model` and bind to a property?

Comment: I'm not using model or ng-value on this form. This form is completely without angular. The only reason angular is depended on the page, is because of notifications on header, which shows notifications and pull latest  notifications. which is not part of the form at all.  but I have removed them also, just to test where is the error, so far if angular.js is loaded, then form is automatically gets bind

Comment: If you're going to use Angular, it will automatically bind those classes to any form, that's just the way it works. There is no way to turn it off, or not use it in certain instances.  You will have to change your form to use Angular, or change your notifications to not use Angular.  I'm sorry I don't have a better solution for you.